# What is the rule used to solve this equation?

Tags: circuit-analysis

This is the quetion :
Find the capacitive reactance that when connected in parallel with the load will make the
load look purely resistive.
[image]

And this is the answer
[image]

Comment: -1; At least take the effort to write down the question.

Comment: @eis3nheim  What were you able to figure out so far?

Comment: @Nick Alexeev What do you mean ?

Comment: @eis3nheim  For the most part, [I mean this](http://meta.electronics.stackexchange.com/a/5120/7036).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the answers provided along with the question (in image) seems wrong(99%, as i haven't done the calculations)

> > for your question you need to know the concept of Leading and lagging VAR. **the pure resistive load never consumes VARs, but capacitance consumes lagging and inductor consumes leading VARs**(*****mark this consuming leading and lagging vars by inductor and capacitor, its confusing, mentioned in the end of answer). so ***in order to make your load to act like pure resistive, you need to connect to connect a capacitance which can provide the leading reactive power or say leading VAR which is required by the inductor(inductor will consume leading var) in load.***
> >
> > follow the following steps to find out the capacitance.

1) **find voltage across the load.

2) find the reactive power consumed by load. let this VAr be Qi.

3) now we know that capacitor in parallel to load should provide the Qi Var. you already know the voltage, so finding the capacitor is no big deal**

****capacitor consumes lagging Var and puts leading Var in the circuit. whereas, inductor consumes leading Var and puts lagging Vars in the circuit.***

Answer (score 1):

Purely resistive loads have a real reactance, while inductive and capacitive loads are imaginary reactances. You simply need to provide a capacitive reactance that has the same but opposite value as the inductive reactance the circuit already has.

Comment: But why the admittance, and why the imaginary part ?
Please explain more

Answer (score 0):

The admittance of the capacitor that we wish to add in parallel will only have an imaginary component which is opposite of the imaginary part of the admittance of the load. We change the load impedance to admittance to simplify things because admittances add in parallel. So for the problem, Y(load) = 5.33 - j4 mS so the admittance of the capacitor needed (which does not have a real component) goes to Y(capacitor) = j4 mS. Now the question asks for the reactance of the capacitor so taking the reciprocal of Y(capacitor) yields
Z(capacitor) = -j250 ohms which goes to X(capacitor) = -250 ohms.
Hope this helps someone in the future!